# Android TextInputEditText flooding logs with requestLayout() warnings when using endIconMode attribute

Tags: java, android

I have a layout with two text input fields, which disappear & re-appear as options change.

However, when I use attribute `app:endIconMode="clear_text"`, these two warnings flood the logs without end, for both of the text fields.

> W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by
>   com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText{ba3099c
>   VFED..CL. ......ID 0,0-1244,272 #7f0a00c6 app:id/homeInput} during
>   layout: running second layout pass
>
> W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by
>   com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText{f641714
>   VFED..CL. ......ID 0,0-1244,224 #7f0a00e6 app:id/lockInput} during
>   layout: running second layout pass

The text fields that are visible depends on `RadioButton` selections

Snippet of one of the text field XMLs:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/alt_sub"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_sub">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/lockInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_+"
        android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Whenever I call `setText()` or `setHint()` in the Activity class, the warning starts to pop up. The warnings only stop when the text field is empty.

I feel that this may be related to the attribute `app:endIconMode="clear_text"`, but I can't find a way to use it without getting these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with different endIconModes and didn't find any solution on the internet so I opened a defect with google:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132651327

The issue was fixed today and it should work properly in `com.google.android.material v1.1.0-alpha07` when it will be released this week.